# Predict with single factor

Tags: r, lm, predict

I'm trying to use a linear model to predict some rasters.

This is my model:

```
model1 <- lm(y~x)
model2 <- lm(y~x+c)
```

c is a country factor, one level for each country code. I want to use the `predict` function, where my new x values come in one raster for each country.

```
library(raster)
ntl <- readRaster("ntl_BRA.tif")
ctry <- "BRA"

p1 = predict(model1, newdata=data.frame(x=ntl[]))
p2 = predict(model2, newdata=data.frame(x=ntl[],c=ctry))
```

The prediction works slow, but fine for model number one (without factors). However, when including a factor in the model I get the following error:

> cannot allocate vector of size 31.9 Gb

There is only one single factor used for each country/raster layer, so to me it doesn't seem like it would need that much extra memory.

Am I defining the factor incorrectly?

Here are the details of the data:

```
> ntl
> class       : RasterLayer 
> dimensions  : 4347, 4957, 21548079  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
> resolution  : 0.004166667, 0.004166667  (x, y)
> extent      : -8.668749, 11.98542, 18.97708, 37.08958  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
> data source : in memory
> names       : layer 
> values      : -4.60517, 9.519959  (min, max)
```

and the data i create the model from :

```
> str(rdata)
'data.frame':   1659 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: num  9.39 9.12 8.53 10.83 8.03 ...
 $ y: num  8.81 8.77 9.25 9.24 9.17 ...
 $ c: Factor w/ 198 levels "ABW","AFG","AGO",..: 190 190 147 147 147 147 147 147 147 147 ...
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. Include the packages you use. You could use `raster::predict` instead.

Comment: I put up some more details. Using raster::predict produces the same problems